# Extracting ID from file using python script?

Tags: python, ubuntu, bioinformatics

[image]

I'm trying to extract just the sequence ID from the the file in Linux server.
To give you few examples `TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1.p1` and `TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i3.p1` and sequence IDs. The sequence ID lengths are not same but they all start with `TRINITY` and ends with `.p1`.

I tried using `awk '{print$1}' filename.cdhit > seq_id.fasta` but instead I got this
[image]

I just want the ID but it would also extract non-interest information as well (the lengthy alphabetic protein seq).
I have attempted to create a python script in hopes to just extract the IDs:

```
import re

file_path = '/var2/user/de_novo/data/transdecoder_dir/Trinity.fasta.transdecoder.pep.cdhi
t'
new_file_path = '/var2/user/de_novo/data/transdecoder_dir/seqID.fasta'

with open(file_path, 'rt') as file:
    for myline in file:
        if "\.p1" in file:
            with open(new_file_path, 'w') as new_file:
                new_file.write()
        else:
            print('No match found.')
```

Tried creating python script, running linux command
But comes out as not match found. Not sure where I went wrong.
Would appreciate with any help, thank you.

Comment: Can you also provide where newlines are in your files?

Comment: There's quite a lot wrong with that code. "re" imported but not used.  you're iterating over "file" using "myline" but attempting to match ".\py" against the whole file and not "myline"; "\.py" is a string literal and the "." doesn't need escaping; And "new_file.write()" isn't passing anything to be written, so if anything was found it would throw an exception

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
awk '{print$1}' filename.cdhit | grep TRINITY | cut -c2-
```

---

As for python, check out https://biopython.org/. It's a collection of bioinformatics-related goodies.

OR

Here a '.cdhit'-file reader:
https://pypi.org/project/cdhit-reader/

Comment: awk '$1~/^>TRINITY/{print}' filename.cdhit

Comment: @cybe when I tried the code I got this result
`TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1.p1
TRINITY_DN0_c0_g2_i3.p1
TRINITY_DN10002_c0_g1_i1.p1
TRINITY_DN10002_c0_g1_i2.p1
TRINITY_DN10002_c1_g1_i1.p1`
Somehow the DN numbers are all changed....

Comment: So we maybe misunderstand what you want :) 
For explanation: the 'DN'-number is not changing. Your file includes lines starting with any character (removed by 'cut -c2-') followed by the string "TRINITY". These lines are split using the default delimiter "space" and the first element is printed (awk '{print$1}'
I guess you want all lines including a specific "DN"-number? Then extent the grep command by it. -> … |  grep TRINITY_DN<number> | …

Answer (score 0):

you can combine that `awk | grep | cut` into :

> ```
> mawk 'sub(".",_, $(NF = /TRINITY/))'
> ```

1. using `regex` to set `NF = 1/0`, which is same as `print $1 | grep`
2. when it's false, `NF` is set to `0`, so whole line is blanked out, thus `sub()` will fail and return a `0` (# instances replaced), thus skipping ineligible lines
3. the `sub()` does same thing as `cut`

Comment: Same issue as cybe's solution I get this
`TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1.p1
TRINITY_DN0_c0_g2_i3.p1
TRINITY_DN10002_c0_g1_i1.p1
TRINITY_DN10002_c0_g1_i2.p1
TRINITY_DN10002_c1_g1_i1.p1
TRINITY_DN10006_c0_g1_i1.p1
TRINITY_DN10006_c0_g1_i4.p1`
The DN numbers are all changed, it shouldn't be

Comment: @Caroline : can u give me 3 cases, in copy-n-pasteable text, of what's before and what *should be* after ?